# Accessing another container on 172.17.0.1 no longer working on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I've got two containers running via a `docker-compose` file. One is calling the other using `172.17.0.1` (instead of `localhost`). This has been working fine for a long time, but has suddenly stopped working.

I suspect it might be some new anti-something-ware installed by company that might be blocking it, but I don't know how to figure out if that is the case. What can I do to debug this?

I know that I can use `host.docker.internal`, but I want this to work out of the box on Linux as well (and know *why* it has stopped working on Windows).

Comment: Depending on the IP address assigned to the host is not going to be portable. If you want containers in two different docker-compose files to talk to each other, I think I'd create an external bridge network and have them communicate over that, using their service names.